# How to open console for a specific java process

Tags: java, eclipse

I am running 4 different process in eclipse and 1 of the process keep logging the message to the console. How can I open and attach the console to specific process in eclipse. Even if I have 4 different console the content of the consoles is keep changing to the processing which is logging the latest message. Which I do not want. All I want is four dedicated console so that I can debug every process separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do have 4 separate consoles, they are just all in the same tab.  To make matters worse, as you mentioned, as soon as one console changes, Eclipse flips to that console automatically.  However, that is a feature you should be able to disable.  There should be a button to the right of the console tab that says "Show Console When Standard Output Changes".

[image]

You toggle that button on or off for each console to prevent the annoying behavior when you have multiple consoles producing a lot of output.  (The button next to it controls the same behavior for standard error.)

You can then toggle between your consoles manually

Answer (score 0):

There is a `Pin Console` button in the Console View action bar to keep a console shown. There are also `Show Console when Standard Output Changes` and `Show Console when Standard Error Changes` buttons.